# No applicable name scope exists WPF error

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I created simple rectangle ->make into control and then added it to new resourcedictionary . I am getting  error when i am trying to animate it.  "No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'rectangle' error" .

How can I fixed this from xaml ?(i know that is sometihing wrong with namescopes but i want to fix it in xaml) tanks for help

Comment: Xaml for name spaces and Resources would be helpful

Comment: OK i think i got it i had to move my storyboard from ControlTemplate.Resources

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix it in XAML if the control was created in code. You register the control in a [`NameScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.aspx).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx)

> If the name is not registered, the added object cannot be referenced by name through methods such as FindName, and you cannot use that name for animation targeting.

See also the [Storyboards Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx) there is an example of how to deal with dynamically added controls.